# distinct request and number of occurences per result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and I don't really know the best way to do my request.

Let's considere a simple exemple. I got this set in my db :

```
{ "_id": 1, "dept": "A"}
{ "_id": 2, "dept": "B"}
{ "_id": 3, "dept": "A"}
{ "_id": 4, "dept": "A"}
```

My result should be an array containing the dept and the number of dept for each

that would be [{dept: "A", nbrofresult: 3}, {dept: "B", nbrofresult: 1}]

So the distinct request is not really a problem i do

```
find().distinct('dept').exec((err, res) => {
    var myarray = res // here I got ["A", "B"]

    // what I was thinking about but looks ugly
    var finalresult = [];
    myarray.forEach((elem) => {
       finalresult.push({ dept: elem, nbrofresult: some other request with count ? })
    })
})
```

Is there a proper way to do that request ? thank you for reading !

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct, there is an easier and faster method on this functionality.
Essentially you are trying to do a aggregation with a map reduce function as described in the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/#map-reduce)

Their docs explains it way better and detailed on how to achieve this.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer I am gonna read this.